# How to break a long line in double quotes?

Tags: c++, formatting

For instance, in my C++ code:

```
setStyleSheet
(
    "QPushButton{background-color:#9dce2c; border-radius:7px; border:1px solid #83c41a; color:#000000; font-size:15px; font-weight:bold; padding:4px 24px; text-decoration:none; }"
    "QPushButton:pressed { border:2px; solid black; }"
    "QPushButton:hover { background-color:grey; }"
    "QPushButton:focus { outline: none; }"
    "QGroupBox { font-size:15px; font-weight:bold; padding:6px 0px; text-decoration:underline; }"
);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C and C++ automatically concatenate adjacent string literals, so you can just do

```
setStyleSheet
    (
        "QPushButton{background-color:#9dce2c; border-radius:7px;"
        "  border:1px solid #83c41a; color:#000000; font-size:15px;"
        "  font-weight:bold; padding:4px 24px; text-decoration:none; }"
        // ...
    );
```

and it will work as intended. (The indentation is not necessary here, but I think it would be good style to indicate that the second and third lines here are intended to be continuations of the first.)

Answer (score 3):

Brian's got the right idea (indeed - you were already using this technique, with all the long lines being concatenated), but if you want there to be one space after each semi-colon, you'll need to move the quotes correspondingly....

```
setStyleSheet
(
    "QPushButton{background-color:#9dce2c; border-radius:7px; "
        "border:1px solid #83c41a; color:#000000; font-size:15px; "
        "font-weight:bold; padding:4px 24px; text-decoration:none; }"
    "QPushButton:pressed { border:2px; solid black; }"
    "QPushButton:hover { background-color:grey; }"
    "QPushButton:focus { outline: none; }"
    "QGroupBox { font-size:15px; font-weight:bold; padding:6px 0px; "
        "text-decoration:underline; }"
);
```

(You can end lines with `\n"` to inject newlines if you want the output easier to read).

Comment: Yeah, you're right, it's probably better to indent the quotes.

Comment: @BrianBi I actually just wanted to comment on your answer, but it's hard to write about multi-line layout on a single line!  Cheers.